What mathematical space are we using in communication theory?
In just about every communication theory paper I've come across, there is no mention of what mathematical space(s) we are working in. Let's suppose the kind of paper I'm thinking about mentions standard mathematical objects we might find in an undergraduate signals and systems course plus stochastic processes. I won't list them all out but, for example, consider: sinusoids, complex exponentials, $\mathrm{e}^{\pm \alpha t}$, $\delta(t)$, the Heaviside step function, and white noise. We usually also use the $L^2$ inner product to compute, for instance, the "energy" of a signal.
At this point, it would be nice to say we work in Hilbert spaces but that does not sit quite right with me; there may be some subtleties I've overlooked that make Hilbert spaces inappropriate. One complication I see is that we would need to have a good definition for the inner product of every element with itself. However, taking the $L^2$ inner product of the Dirac delta distribution with itself, i.e., $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta^2(t) \mathrm{d}t$ is not well defined, from my cursory reading of the matter. Apparently there is a "Colombeau algebra" that needs to be invoked but that is a rabbit hole I do not want to go down unless it is the only path forward.
Here I've assumed that I only care about continuous-time, but I am also interested in this same question for discrete-time communication theory.
The reason why this matters is that I want to be able to use methods from functional analysis on certain communication theory problems but to invoke theorems, I need to be sure about what kind of space(s) I want to work in.

I don't know myself.  Does a Sobolev space fit the bill?

This thing about spaces reminds me of a graduate course I took in Functional Analysis, which had metric spaces, Banach spaces (metric spaces with a norm and zero and additive), and Hilbert spaces (Banach spaces with an inner product added). We used a book by Kreyszig.

You can think of your communications space as having symbols to communicate, each with their own coordinates in a vector space.  A metric space is a generalization of the vector space.  You can measure the distance between two vectors in this space, one might be a received signal and the other is a constellation of all possible symbols there are to transmit.  Then your job is to find the symbol that most closely matches the demodulated received signal.

We work in countless different spaces, and in other mathematical structures that aren't spaces, depending on what we do for which purpose on what signal.
For example: we often like to consider a set of signals that we can Fourier transform. That's nice, but it's simply not possible for all signals, and sometimes we want to deal (especially) with these.
Other example: While your sampled signals might be representable as vectors in $\mathbb C^N$, the error-correction code you're using might be in a finite field, e.g. $\text{GF}(256)^M$. The stream of samples or symbol would have to be accounted for as infinitely-dimensional, if you want to make statements on different infinite symbols, so no $N$ or $M$ that you could work with. We regularly consider the probabilities of things happening, so our receptions (no matter in which of the above fields we consider them) might get mapped to some Borel algebra.
So, really, this is math and engineering: the problem defines the tool, not the application area.
